# How to create account with Class of Service using SOAP Zimbra

Tags: soap, ldap, zimbra

Hi i need to create a user with Class of Service "stuff" on Zimbra. I am using zimbra soap services and mu request is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <context xmlns="urn:zimbra">
            <authToken>MyAuth</authToken>
        </context>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CreateAccountRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
            <name>mitar.miric.5412@metropolitan.ac.rs</name>
            <password>PromeniMe123</password>
            <a n="givenName">Mitar</a>
            <a n="sn">Mirić</a><a n="cn">Mitar Mirić</a>
            <a n="displayName">Mitar Mirić</a>
        </CreateAccountRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried to put cos (Class of Service) as a `<a n="cos">` but it not worked.
Does any one know how to create a user using soap and add him to COS called "stuff".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I added `<a n="zimbraCOSId">` and copy the id for stuff from LDAP.